# Generating and downloading an `Excel` document breaks `ASP.net` LoginStatus

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In my ASP.net web application I have a page which shows a (not very complicated) table. I have implemented a button so when the (registered) members clicks on it, the browser downloads the table as an `Excel` document

The code to generate this `Excel` is as follow:

```
        Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
        ' first let's clean up the response.object
        response.Clear()
        response.Charset = ""
        Dim filename As String = MapPath("~/ex1.xls")
        ' set the response mime type for excel
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & filename & """")
        ' create a string writer
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Using htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
                ' instantiate a datagrid
                Dim dg As New DataGrid()
                dg.DataSource = dt
                dg.DataBind()

                dg.RenderControl(htw)
                response.Write(sw.ToString())
                response.[End]()
            End Using
        End Using
```

The problem is that this code is breaking somehow the `ASPN.net` `LoginStatus` as when you try to log out after downloading this `Excel` (the "log out" buttom is always visible at the application) every click on the buttom will download the same `Excel`over and over (once per click). If you reload window or change page the "log out" will work again.

this is the "log out" link when inspecting it with chrome:

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_LoginStatus1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$LoginStatus1$ctl00','')">Log Out</a>
```

I have tried to make the `Excel` to download from other page using:

```
onclick="window.document.forms[0].target='_blank';"
```

and now it opens a new tab, download the `Excel`, close the tab (fast process) but still keeps breaking the logout link.

And I run out of ideas, any help, code, hint or whatever possible solution to fix this problem is very welcome.

Comment: Can you post the markup that contains the logout button and the "export to excel" button as well?

Comment: Ty Tasos. I alredy solved it somehow chaging the code to another page and changing `asp:LinkButton` for `asp:HyperLink`. No idea why it doesn't work for a link buttom but the problem is, at least, solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new page within the blank target, and let the new page generate the excel

Comment: As I have said int he question, I tried it but still not working

Comment: What i mean is to create an entirely new page and open it with a blank target, not to just open the already existing page in a blank target..could you try this?

Comment: I did what you said and it was still not working but after chaging `asp:LinkButton` for `asp:HyperLink` it's working ok. Still don't know why linkbuttom not working but at least it's solved. Would be great to know, though, why It needs a new page to do something supposily, so easy.

Comment: LoginStatus wants to perform a postback.. With your code you are changing the normal flow of postbacks. Changing from LinkButton to Hyperlink you're not performing a post anymore but a get request, so it works..would need further investigation to understand why your original code is not working though

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a server side error.
Your code to logout actually runs the code to download Excel.
May be you should throw in a 'Response.End();' in the click handler for logout.

Answer (score 0):

Well a quick work around would be to use report viewer control, which has an export to excel functionality.

I know this solution is not exactly what you were looking for, but from my experience when a user is looking for excel functionality, instead of providing a table/gridview results to the user i provide an rdlc report, which has all the export functionality.